# Best calculation to determine if there is a cause effect relationship?

Tags: correlation

On a diet analysis kick here but not very knowledgeable about stats. I'm wanting to track what I eat correlates to then how I feel. So, my plan is to track everything I eat and also how I feel. So, my data will look like longer versions of this :

rice : 2/9/2017, 2/11/2017, 2/20/2017....
wheat : ....
fruit : ....

And how I feel (I'm thinking -5 to +5)

I feel|date : 4|2/9/2017,  2|2/10/2017, -4|2/11/2017....

So, how would I determine if maybe rice makes me feel good whilst wheat makes me feel crappy? Of note, I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction, ie name of calculation so I can go figure it out, not for anybody to do it for me.

Comment: First of all correlation does not mean causation. Your proposed experiment is unsuited to infer causality (see [randomized experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_experiment)). There are multiple different things you could do. However, learn some basic stats first (Coursera or others) and then move your way to time series analysis and regression models.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **ordered logistic regression** if your dependent variable is measured on ordered scale (-5 to +5). But to keep things simple from the beginning I would just switch to binary dependent variable (happy/unhappy) and use ordinary logistic regression.

From the experiment point of view, it seems to me the best is to prepare a plan for what you will eat in the next months day by day and to follow the plan. This way it should be ensured that you don't just pick up food according to how you feel (inverse causality)